# Conjugacy classes in $SU_2$

Tags: group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, linear-groups

I'm trying to find all conjugacy classes in $SU_2$.

Matrices in $SU_2$ are of the form:

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
       \alpha & \beta \\
       - \bar{\beta} & \bar{\alpha} 
     \end{bmatrix}$ and $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2  =1$

I thought I could use Jordan decomposition to do this and here's what I've got so far:

$W(M) = X^2 - trM \cdot X + \det M = X^2 - (\alpha + \bar{\alpha})X + 1$

so the eigenvalues are: $\lambda_{1} = \frac{\alpha + \bar{\alpha} + \sqrt{(\alpha + \bar{\alpha})^2 +4}}{2}, \ \ \lambda_{2} = \frac{\alpha + \bar{\alpha} - \sqrt{(\alpha + \bar{\alpha})^2 +4}}{2}$.

1) $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ if $(\alpha + \bar{\alpha})^2 \neq 4, \ \ \alpha = a+bi, \ \ a \neq \sqrt{2}, - \sqrt{2} $

and then $M$ is diagonizable and $M = S\begin{bmatrix}
       \lambda & 0 \\
       0 & \lambda 
     \end{bmatrix} S^{-1}$

2) a) if $\beta=0,  (\alpha + \bar{\alpha})^2 = 4$, then $M$ is diagonal

b) if  $\beta=0,  (\alpha + \bar{\alpha})^2 \neq 4$, then $M$ is not diagonizable and $M = S\begin{bmatrix}
       \lambda & 1 \\
       0 & \lambda 
     \end{bmatrix} S^{-1}$

But in order to find conjugacy classes I need those $S \in SU_2$ and I don't know what to do next. Maybe there's a better way to approach this problem?

I'll be grateful for all your help.

Update:

If we let $S = \begin{bmatrix}
       x & y \\
       - \bar{y} & \bar{x} 
     \end{bmatrix} $

then in case 1) $SMS^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
       \lambda_1 & 0 \\
       0 & \lambda_2 
     \end{bmatrix}$ and after multiplying those matrices I got these four equations:

$\bar{xy}(\bar{\alpha} - \alpha) + \bar{\beta} (\bar{x})^2 + \beta (\bar{y})^2=0$

$xy(\bar{\alpha} - \alpha) + \beta x^2 + \beta y^2=0$

$\bar{\alpha} y \bar{y} + \alpha x \bar{x} + \beta \bar{y} x - \bar{\beta} y \bar{x} = \lambda_1$

$\bar{\alpha} y \bar{y} + \alpha x \bar{x} - \beta \bar{y} x + \bar{\beta} y \bar{x} = \lambda_2$.

Could those equations be helpful?

Comment: You mean $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$, which just says that $\det_{\mathbb{C}} = 1$.

Comment: Well, yes, it does. I used it while computing eigenvalues. I'll correct the missing $2$s.

Comment: Note that the characteristic polynomial of $A \in SU(2)$ has real coefficients, so the eigenvalues are complex conjugates. Moreover, the product of the eigenvalues is $\det_{\mathbb C} A = 1$. What do these together imply about the eigenvalues?

Comment: Those imply that $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)=(a+bi, a-bi), \ a^2+b^2=1$

Comment: Correct, and what do these constraints mean geometrically?

Comment: That these are points on the unit circle lying on opposite sides of $y$ axis. I don't see yet how that helps.

Comment: Note also that since $SU(2)$ is compact, all of its elements are diagonalizable.

Comment: You see, I haven't had Topological Groups course yet. Is there any other way to prove that all matrices in $SU_2$ are diagonizable?

Comment: In this case you don't need any knowledge about topological groups, just that $SU(2)$, regarded as a certain set of pairs in $\mathbb{C}^2$, is bounded, which follows immediately from the determinant computation. (In fact, this shows that $SU(2)$ is just the unit $3$-sphere in $\mathbb{C}^2 \leftrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$.)

Comment: That said, if you want to avoid topology altogether and know what a normal matrix is, you can use that since $SU(2) \subset U(2)$, $A \in SU(2)$ satisfies $AA^* = I = A^*A$, so $A$ is normal and hence diagonalizable.

Comment: I see. I haven't noticed that. Thank you. Could you tell me how to determine / classify conjugacy classes in $SU_2$? If every matrix is diagonozable, then a conjugacy class consists of a diagonal matrix and ...? You wrote that we can identify this group with the unit $3$- sphere. Can we identify the conjugacy classes with certain parts of the sphere?

Comment: First, note that if two matrices are in the same conjugacy class, they must have the same eigenvalues, so all of the matrices $\text{diag}(e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta}) \in SU(2)$, $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ are in distinct conjugacy classes. To prove that this exhausts them, you need something like a converse for this statement, and it is provided by the Spectral Theorem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix .

Comment: I realized our comments here essentially contain a proof, which I've written up as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the characteristic polynomial of any matrix $A \in SU(2)$ has real coefficients, its eigenvalues are complex conjugates $\lambda, \bar{\lambda}$; since $\lambda \bar{\lambda} = \det A = 1$, the eigenvalues are $e^{i \theta}, e^{-i \theta}$ for some unique $\theta \in [0, \pi]$.

If two matrices are in the same conjugacy class, they are similar and so have the same eigenvalues. Thus, all of the diagonal matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix} e^{i \theta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\theta} \end{pmatrix} \in SU(2), \qquad \theta \in [0, \pi],$$ are in distinct classes.

Conversely, since any $A \in SU(2)$ is normal, by the [Spectral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) it is unitarily equivalent (conjugate via an element of $U(2)$) to a diagonal matrix, which must be of the above form. In fact, we can easily show that it is conjugate via an element of $SU(2)$, so the classes containing the above diagonal matrices actually exhaust the conjugacy classes.

**Edit** Via the identification
$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta \\ -\bar{\beta} & \bar\alpha\end{pmatrix} \leftrightarrow (\alpha, \beta)$$
we can regard $SU(2)$ as the subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ for which $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$, namely as the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \cong \mathbb{C}^2$.

As @Don pointed out in his comment, the conjugacy classes are latitude $2$-spheres in $\mathbb{S}^3$ (except for the north and south pole, which are singleton classes). There are several ways to see this, and here's one:

The conjugation action of $SU(2)$ on $\Bbb C^2$ decomposes into actions on the trace and tracefree parts of a matrix, via $$A \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr} A\right) I + \left[A - \left(\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr} A\right) I \right].$$

On the other hand, conjugation fixes the identity matrix, so the action on the tracefree part is trivial, and one can show that the action on the set of tracefree matrices preserves a definite quadratic form $Q$, inducing a map $SU(2) \to SO(3)$; this map is a double cover and in particular acts transitively on each of the spheres $\{Q(x) = r\}$ of the quadratic form.

In short, the conjugacy class of
$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta \\ -\bar{\beta} & \bar\alpha\end{pmatrix} \in SU(2)$$
consists of exactly the elements
$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha' & \beta' \\ -\bar{\beta}' & \bar\alpha'\end{pmatrix} \in SU(2)$$
such that $$\Re \alpha = \Re \alpha',$$
but this is just the intersection of $SU(2) \cong \mathbb{S}^3$ with a hyperplane with coordinate $\Re \alpha$.

**Remark** Much of the above can be said more cleanly in the language of the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, which I avoided above because people often encounter $SU(2)$ before they do quaternions: In summary, the group multiplication rule for $SU(2)$ can be identified with multiplication of (unit) quaternions, the splitting $\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}^3$ is just the decomposition of $\mathbb{H}$ into real and imaginary parts, and these are the irreducible subrepresentations of $\mathbb{H}$ regarded as an $SU(2)$-module under the conjugation action. Then, the conjugacy classes (the orbits under the conjugation action) are just the intersections of the unit sphere $SU(2) \cong \mathbb{S}^3$ with the hyperplanes with given (quaternionic) real part.

Comment: Thank you. I've read a little about $SU_2$ and $S^3$. Could you tell me how we can identify the conjugacy classes with circles of latitude of $S^3$?

Comment: You're welcome, and sure, the details are a little involved, so I simply appended it to my answer.

Comment: How do we use the spectral theorem to directly show that the latitudes consist of conjugacy classes?

Comment: @Bach You can get one of the inclusions just by expanding the action of the conjugation of $\operatorname{diag}\left(e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta}\right)$ by a general element of $SU(2)$, observing that the trace is invariant (always equal to $2 \cos \theta$), and then interpreting that trace as parameterizing the latitude $2$-spheres as the part of my answer after **Edit** describes.